# Remove markers from a GMapPanel version 3. ExtJS

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, extjs, google-maps-markers

Is there a way to remove markers from a GMapPanel?  I was looking through the GMapPanel code and only saw a function that hides the markers on the map.  I'm trying to remove markers so i can re populate the map with new markers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[part of this link](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/ux/GMapPanel.js) :

```
addMarker : function(point, marker, clear, center, listeners){

    Ext.applyIf(marker,G_DEFAULT_ICON);

    if (clear === true){
        this.getMap().clearOverlays();
    }
    if (center === true) {
        this.getMap().setCenter(point, this.zoomLevel);
    }

    var mark = new GMarker(point,marker);
    if (typeof listeners === 'object'){
        for (evt in listeners) {
            GEvent.bind(mark, evt, this, listeners[evt]);
        }
    }
    this.getMap().addOverlay(mark);

},
```

it appears that `.addMarker(false, false, true, false, false);`

or try calling: `this.getMap().clearOverlays();`

Comment: Thanks! the .addMarker(false,false,true,false,false); worked!